# Como abrir uma nova janela pop-up ao clicar em qualquer lugar da página?

Tags: javascript, popup

Estou querendo fazer com que após o **visitante** clicar em qualquer lugar da minha página fazer abrir uma **janela pop-up** atrás da janela principal que o visitante está. Assim ele não irá ver a janela que foi aberta.

Eu estou usando essa função:

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.onclick = function( e )
    {
        window.open( 'http://www.google.com.br' );
    }
}
```

O problema dessa função acima é que ele só abre uma nova aba.

Eu gostaria que ela abrisse como esta função abaixo:

```
function myFunction() {
     window.open("http://google.com.br", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=1, left=1, width=1, height=1");     
}
```

Porém com essa função acima ele só abre se estiver um botão para clicar.
Queria que ele abrir-se quando da um click em qualquer lugar da pagina.
Porém atras da janela principal.

Comment: você quer fazer algo sem que o usuário saiba? não me parece ético.

Comment: Boa noite Seth, não use tags irrelevantes, as tags devem se referir ao problema, ajaxe node.js nada tem haver com a situação. Recomendo que leia: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging - Tenho certeza que você vai levar este comentário como uma critica construtiva :)

Comment: Estou querendo fazer isso para um portal de video meu, como não vou ter patrocinadores, eu estarei usando sistemas ADS para que eu possa ganhar o meu dinheiro. então essa foi a unica forma que eu achei para todos os visitante que entrar gerar um clique pra mim nos anuncios sem eles saberem, não quero prejudicar ninguem e a janela só sera aberto uma vez apenas depois não abrirá mais.

Comment: Desculpe amigos mas eu não conheço muito as regras do site. Esto muito focado em conseguir solucionar essa duvida que estou. sera que consegue me ajudar?

Comment: Espero que os desenvolvedores de *browser's add-ons* vejam esta pergunta/resposta e encontrem bloqueio para esse tal `clique ... sem eles saberem`. Troço horroroso. Mas,  +1 pela pergunta bem feita.

Answer (score 1):

Coloque a função fora do `window.onload` que funcionará.

**Exemplo:**

```
document.onclick = function( e ){
 myFunction();
}

function myFunction() {
window.open("http://google.com.br", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=1, left=1, width=1, height=1");
}
```

Veja funcionando no [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/50L50g58/1/)

O window.onload é desparado somente após todos os arquivos html,css,imagens forem carregadas, agora se você precisa apenas do HTML(DOM) você pode utilizar sem ou colocar um `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: Desculpe Gabriel, mas preciso comentar a sua resposta, o `addEventListener` não foi o que resolveu o problema, a única coisa que fez foi trocar onclick por addEventListener, o que resolveu o problema do AP foi colocar myFunction dentro do evento, pessoalmente acho que este deveria ser o foco da resposta. Tenho certeza que vai levar o meu como uma critica construtiva :)

Comment: Claro que levo como uma critica construtiva, o #SO é para isto, realizei alguns testes e utilizando o document.onclick funcionará da mesma forma, a diferença  aqui, foi no window.onload, que pelo que percebi não carrega a tempo de ser executada

Comment: Pra mim o que importa é que ele esta ajudando o menino a solucionar o problema, Acho que conhecimento nem um deve ter critica e sim questionamento e resposta, Gabriel voce fez bem respondeu como todos devem responder e não ficar dizendo a isso é não é etico.

Comment: Gabriel eu apoio voce, o que importa é que voce esta ajudando aos amigos com duvida tirar as duvidas e nao fica criticando com o que é etico. o importa é que conhecimento nunca é de mais.

Comment: Gabriel eu fico muito agradecido pela sua ajuda, voce ja me ajudou a solucionar o que eu na estava conseguindo fazer. Agora eu só preciso conseguir fazer essa janelinha abrir atrás na janela principal

Comment: Guilheme muito obrigado tambem pela ajuda mas o que falta pra mim  fazer essa janelinha abrir atraz da janela principal :D

Comment: Guilherme Muito obrigado por acionar o questionamento do grabriel para que possamos melhor sempre mais e mais.

Comment: A proposta do SO é ajudar com ética. Ficou muito claro o que você está tentando fazer, se o usuário entra no seu site, você quer ganhar dinheiro à força bruta. Cada um entra no site que quiser.